# Is it possible for iframe height to be set by the content provider?

Tags: html, iframe

The situation:

Site *abc* is gives *def* an iframe (or a div, or whatever will make the last part work). 
The iframe is pulling content from *abc*
The iframe cuts off the content because *def* has set a too-small height.
*abc* wants to control the height of the iframe.

Is this possible with the restrictions on JS?

Comment: The question asked is a little confusing. Could you add some code examples? And if I'm interpreting your question correctly, you can't control the height of an iframe from inside the iframe due to security restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both parent and frame pages are in the same domain, you can cross script. if they are on different domains, most browsers will restrict this.